# Efficient approach for multiple 'or' statements in an conditional statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements

Only a few months into learning Python, so bear with me...

Creating a very simple game as part of Python tutorial, wherein essentially the user bounces from class to class, all of which require user input and print out various statements.

For example, given the following class:

```
class ChipCar(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "What's up? Get in the Bran Muffin car!"

        action = raw_input(">  ")

        if action == "shut up chip":
            print "Screw you!"
            print action
            return next_scene('Your_death')
            #return 'Death' 
        elif action == "hi chip":
            print "What's up loser?!?! Let's go to O&A..."
            return next_scene('Chip_in_studio')
        else:
            print "what's wrong with you? Let's go to my mother's house, I think Lamar's there..."
            return 'Chip_mom_house'
```

Say I want to be able to check for multiple correct options for the first if statement, for example, in addition to `"shut up chip"` say `"go away dude"` or `"screw you"` or `"Java sucks"` — what's the best approach?

Comment: Wow, a lot of options....Kind of goes against Python philosophy, eh? Something about "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def enter(self):
    print "What's up? Get in the Bran Muffin car!"

    action = raw_input(">  ")

    if(action == "shut up chip" or action == "go away dude" or action == "screw you"):
        print "Screw you!"
        print action
        return next_scene('Your_death')
        #return 'Death' 
    elif action == "hi chip":
        print "What's up loser?!?! Let's go to O&A..."
        return next_scene('Chip_in_studio')
    else:
        print "what's wrong with you? Let's go to my mother's house, I think Lamar's there..."
        return 'Chip_mom_house'
```

The way we're using `or` in this conditional statement is that the values are evaluated in a boolean context from left to right, just like with `and`. If any value is true, `or` returns that value immediately. You can think of it in terms of packaging all the different user response options inside the parentheses, wherein we're evaluating to see if each instance of `action` has one of your user input values.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your tests are for equality, you can use the `in` operator on a collection and it will check if the value you're testing is present. I suggest using a `set` as its membership test is very fast, but you might get better performance in Python 2 using a `list` or `tuple` (I think it is only in recent versions of Python 3 that constant set literals are stored as constants rather than being recreated each time a function runs):

```
if action in {"shut up chip", "go away dude", "screw you", "Java sucks"}:
    # ...
```

If you have non-equality tests that are none then less related, you might be able to use the `any` or `all` functions to chain them as if with `or` or `and`. For instance, this code would test for the same strings as above, but would allow arbitrary capitalization and for extra text to be included along side the bit we're checking for (it does a substring search):

```
if any(phrase in action.lower() for phrase in ("shut up chip", "go away dude",
                                               "screw you", "java sucks")):
    # ...
```

This is using a generator expression inside the `any` call, a very common idiom in Python (but perhaps a bit more advanced than what you've learned).

Comment: Thanks for this one. Regarding the cool generator expression option you provided: what would happen though if the user input included both a phrase in the current tuple as well as a phrase that's setup for the `elif` statement, for example `"shut up chip hi chip"`

Comment: Because you're using an `if` and `elif`, only the first one would work (the `elif`'s condition will never be checked). If you want to be able to detect multiple different matches for a single input, you'd probably need to use more complicated logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `in` operator on a tuple of strings. It returns `True` if there is a match.

```
class ChipCar(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "What's up? Get in the Bran Muffin car!"

        action = raw_input(">  ")

        if action in ("shut up chip", "go away dude", "screw you"):
            print "Screw you!"
            print action
            return next_scene('Your_death')
            #return 'Death' 
        elif action == "hi chip":
            print "What's up loser?!?! Let's go to O&A..."
            return next_scene('Chip_in_studio')
        else:
            print "what's wrong with you? Let's go to my mother's house, I think Lamar's there..."
            return 'Chip_mom_house'
```